Getting empty response after calling safeFactory.init() function on Safe MultiSig wallet
I created a multiSig address from the UI and I'm trying to call an external contract using that safe address.
I want to use that safeAddress and create a sort of safe Instance so that I can call createTransaction() for the protocolKit. Here's the link for the code where its done for the second owner
I tried following the docs here
I imported the SafeFactory in the following manner:
const { SafeFactory } = require('@safe-global/protocol-kit');

And I tried initializing it
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init({
provider: rpcUrl,
signer: signerPrivateKey,
});

But I get safeFactory emtpy. Can you please guide?
The parameters rpcUrl and signerPrivateKey are correct but I can't seem to find the solution.

Hey there, what exactly are you trying to do? To deploy a Safe, you'll also need to call the deploySafe method: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe

I created a multiSig address from the UI and I'm trying to call an external contract using safe address.
I want to use that safeAddress and create a sort of safe Instance so that I can createTransaction. Here's the link for the code - https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#confirm-the-transaction-second-confirmation
I have also edited the answer to include all this.

Hey Tanay it worked. I need to use Safe.init() . I was accidentally using SafeFactory.init()

Ah cool, glad to hear that it worked :)
